# Firebase And Kotlin Coroutines

Tags: firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I have this static (companion object) function to download event information from Firebase Firestore and event images from Firebase Storage:

```
fun downloadEventInformationAndImages() {
    FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("events").document(downloadedEventID)
    .get().addOnSuccessListener { snap ->

    //Download Event Information Here
    //Do stuff

    GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
        //Download Event Images Here
        val downloadEventImage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().reference.child("Images/Events/$eventID/eventPhoto.jpeg")
                            .getBytes(1024 * 1024).asDeferred()
        val downloadEventFounderImage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().reference.child("Images/Users/$founderID/profilePhoto.jpeg")
                            .getBytes(1024 * 1024).asDeferred()

        try {
           val downloadedImages = mutableListOf<ByteArray>(
                                downloadEventImage.await(),
                                downloadEventFounderImage.await())
            // Update stuff on UI
        } catch(e: StorageException) {
            // Error handling
        }
     }.addOnFailureListener { exception ->
     // Error handling
     }
    }
}
```

What I want to do is avoid using GlobalScope but when I tried to add `runBlocking` to `downloadEventInformationAndImages()`:

```
fun downloadEventInformationAndImages() = runBlocking {
    // Do stuff
    launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
```

it didn't work (It didn't wait Firebase to finish downloading - then I moved runBlocking to inside of function, also didn't work). How can I avoid using GlobalScope? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can't you just pass a `CoroutineScope` tied to the caller's lifecycle as a parameter of `downloadEventInformationAndImages`?

Comment: Hey @RicardoCosteira ! It works - I am surprised answer was this straightforward - thanks! :) Since I am new to Kotlin and Coroutines, is there a specific thing I should be careful while passing CoroutineScope as a parameter such as memory leak etc?

Comment: Glad it worked :) I'll write up a more detailed answer in a few minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best option I see here is to pass a `CoroutineScope` as a parameter of `downloadEventInformationAndImages`. So that would be

```
fun downloadEventInformationAndImages(scope: CoroutineScope) {
  FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("events").document(downloadedEventID)
  .get().addOnSuccessListener { snap ->

  //Download Event Information Here
  //Do stuff

    scope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) { ... }
  }
}
```

The one thing you have to be careful is that every coroutine you launch here is now launched in the scope you pass in, which means that if it fails or is cancelled, it'll also cancel any parent coroutines. To understand how to deal with this, you should check the documentation for [Jobs](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-job/). On the other hand, you can also build your `CoroutineScope` with a `SupervisorJob` (mentioned in the documentation link above), where child coroutines fail without affecting the parents. Finally, it's also good practice to cleanup your `CoroutineScope` when the object that owns it reaches the end of its lifecycle. This will avoid possible memory leaks. The cleanup can be done either with `scope.cancel()` or `scope.coroutineContext.cancelChildren()`. The first one terminates the scope's job (which gets propagated to all child jobs),  and the second one just cancels any child jobs that may exist. I suggest you spend some of your time just reading articles or even documentation about coroutines, because there are a lot of nuances :)

Answer (score 0):

You can write your function as `CoroutineScope` extension function:

```
fun CoroutineScope.downloadEventInformationAndImages() {
    ...
    launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
    ...
}
```

and call it from ViewModel or some other place with scope:

```
uiScope.downloadEventInformationAndImages()
```

Comment: Hello Andrei! Thanks a lot for your answer. Since I am new to Kotlin and Coroutines, I couldn't implement your answer (the way I should - I think). But the way Ricardo proposed at the comment to first post worked for me. Thanks again though for your answer.

Comment: Hello Metin. No problem :) Extension is very useful Kotlin feature. If you want to know Kotlin well you read this someday https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html